# Auth filter full name

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I need to filter Users (from auth.user) based on their full names. I know I can address a user's full name by `user.get_full_name()`, but is it possible to filter by this attribute?

I need to do something like, `user = User.objects.filter( ... )`, but I need to feed it an attribute. Is there some attribute that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as a property, unfortunately.

The available properties in the Django User model are

- username
- password
- email
- first name
- last name

But doing the filter anyways would look like this

```
User.object.filter(first_name="Jimminy", last_name="Cricket")
```

What you could do is create a custom form of profile.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   full_name = models.CharField()
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.full_name = "Jimminy Cricket" #but not hardcoded ofc.
      super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and filter on it like so

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.get(full_name="Jimminy Cricket")
print profile.user
```

***Update 15/4-2018***

You could also do achieve the same by using the [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()
UserModel.objects.filter(Q(first_name='Jiminy'), Q(last_name='Cricket'))
```

Which would output the following SQL

```
'SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE ("auth_user"."first_name" = Jiminy AND "auth_user"."last_name" = Cricket)'
```

And thusly getting rid of the intermediate model/form.

Comment: Yes. I guess this is the best I can do. I'll split the input (from the user): `name=name.split(' ')`, and then `user = User.objects.filter(first_name=name[0], last_name=name[1])`

Comment: This seems like the best solution, but also an example of a pretty extreme limitation of Django's query language!

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard I wouldn't necessary call it limited - i mean `get_full_name` is still a python property and not related to SQL at all. If you want to drop down to raw SQL that's possible otherwise using the `Q` object would also help here. `User.objects.filter(Q(first_name='Jiminy'), Q(last_name='Cricket'))` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

To filter based on a User's full name, you could first [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) the queryset with each user's full name and then filter on that annotation.

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat


User.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')
).filter(full_name__icontains='J Biz')
```